# How to Grant SELECT on a table containing a varying array

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to allow the role titled **Head** to be able to query a table titled **ReportDetails**. The table **ReportDetails** contains a varying array titled **ReportEntries_VA**. I have got as far as testing my database and found that even though I have granted SELECT on **ReportDetails**, **Head** is still not able to access **ReportEntries_VA**.

Code is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE ReportEntries_Type AS OBJECT
(Subject VARCHAR (500));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ReportEntries_VA AS
VARRAY (12) OF ReportEntries_Type;
/

CREATE TABLE ReportDetails
(ReportID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
StudentID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ReportEntries ReportEntries_VA,
DateLastModified DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ReportDetails_PK PRIMARY KEY (ReportID, StudentID),
CONSTRAINT RDStudentIDSD FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
REFERENCES StudentDetails (StudentID));
```

The privilege is then granted to **Head** as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ReportDetails TO Head;
```

Any suggestions as to how I can allow **Head** to access the varying array (and the object created before it?) would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Zulu

Comment: You should use `varchar2` not `varchar`, which is only included in current Oracle releases to help backwards compatibility... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant `EXECUTE` privilege on all the types to your `Head` role.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ReportEntries_Type to Head;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ReportEntries_VA   to Head;
```

See [Managing Oracle Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96594/adobjmng.htm).