# Allowing a role to query, insert upon and update a varying array

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Slight variation on [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9149524/146325)...

I am trying to allow the role titled **Head** to be able to query a table titled **ReportDetails**. The table **ReportDetails** contains a varying array titled **ReportEntries_VA**. I have got as far as testing my database and found that even though I have granted SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE on **ReportDetails**, **Head** is still not able to access **ReportEntries_VA**.

Code is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE ReportEntries_Type AS OBJECT
(Subject VARCHAR (500));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ReportEntries_VA AS
VARRAY (12) OF ReportEntries_Type;
/

CREATE TABLE ReportDetails
(ReportID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
StudentID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ReportEntries ReportEntries_VA,
DateLastModified DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ReportDetails_PK PRIMARY KEY (ReportID, StudentID),
CONSTRAINT RDStudentIDSD FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
REFERENCES StudentDetails (StudentID));
```

The privilege is then granted to Head as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ReportDetails TO Head;
```

I understand that I can use this to query, but not to insert or update:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ReportEntries_Type TO Head;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ReportEntries_VA TO Head;
```

When I try to insert rows I'm getting this: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`, even though I have granted SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE on the table, and execute on the object and varying array. Basically it's not letting me insert into or update the array

Any suggestions as to how I can allow Head to insert upon and alter the varying array (and the object created before it?) would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Zulu

Comment: @FlorinGhita I'm getting this: "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges", even though I have granted SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE on the **table**, and execute on the **object** and **varying array**. Basically it's not letting me insert into or update the array.

Comment: What happens when you grant directly to a user rather than a role?

Comment: you got any triggers on that table?
Try give select to the tables that are constraints for the table you whan't to access

Comment: Can you show us the UPDATE code that is failing? I could not reproduce the error, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant execute on the varray as well.

Comment: Sorry - I see now that you did grant execute on the varray - only it does not show from your code samples.